# How can I make intermediate files in a custom scons builder?

Tags: scons

When scons builds executables from c files, it seems to know about the intermediate object files created.  For example, in this link:

http://www.scons.org/doc/0.93/HTML/scons-user/x364.html

It seems possible to let scons consider or not consider intermediate files when buuilding.

How can I get the same behavior for my custom builder?

Comment: Can you please give an example of what you're trying to accomplish? Do you want to add another source file type such that you get C/CPP objects compiled automatically from them? Or is this a separate toolchain that you want to implement?

Comment: Never mind , I see that the intermediate file support is deprecated in scons. I wanted to tell scons that, when going from a to b to c, b is intermediate and then do something like delete all intermediates or move them or whatever.

Comment: SCons knows about `SideEffect()`s (see [SCons User Guide](http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html)), but I'm not sure that it's what you're looking for. It might solve your problem, but that depends on your concrete use case...that's why I asked for an example.

Comment: My build process has 4 steps per file: preprocess, then compile to 3d STL file, then unify near vertices.  Currently, each step is a new target.  I thought that there might be a more correct way to deal with those intermediate files.  If the way that I'm doing it now, 3 targets per step, is proper, then my question is moot.

Comment: You need a separate builder for each step (= transition from source to target file). But what you can do in SCons is to chain these builders, such that you can write `env.UnifyVertices('target', 'source.preprocess')`. When setup correctly, SCons sees that the `UnifyVertices` builder actually needs an STL file as input. It then may search for a builder that delivers a `*.stl` and try to get a source file from there. If this is what you want, then update your question with a concrete example (filenames/-extensions). Hint: Search for `src_builder` in the MAN page..a pseudo-Builder might help too.